# Doctrine Symfony ManyToMany join table as OneToMany to other table

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine, many-to-many, one-to-many

can anybody please tell me whether technically with Doctrine this is possible:

When i have 2 entities, which are linked to each other as manytomany in a third table.

Is it possible than to link this third table manytomany also to one another table as onetomany?
Please note, i have already an entity for manytomany as i needed extra fields in it.

Thx
Regards

Comment: Not really clear to me what you asking.  Out of the box a Doctrine many to many relation automatically creates and 'hides' an intermediate relationship table.  Instead of using a many to many relation you can explicitly create an intermediate entity and setup one to many relations with the original entities.  At which point you can additional properties to the intermediate entity including additional relations to even more entities.  Just a bit more work.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the manytomany table define like a "independent" table, yes, you can add a foreign key to references other tables; but if you create the manytomany relation by adding two atributes, one in the first table and one in the second, you can a table manytomany that cant hold more atributes.